# Set Resolution for Old Sony TV

Tags: raspi-config

I am using an old sony TV, the resolution is coming up very flickery, is there any way to change the hertz rate and resolution.

PI is selecting

1920 x 1080

TV says 1080i @ 50hz

But its so flickery, ive played around with config.txt.

Does anyone have a list of the different modes available ?

ie the settings for 1366x768 @ 50hz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the hdmi_mode and hdmi_group values in config.txt. The [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md) for config.txt has all the details and values for these parameters.

I would try these values to start:

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=20
```

If after making these changes you may want to change the **config_hdmi_boost** value, and try a different cable.

Comment: awesome exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: **Just remember to ensure you have a way to reset it if you come up with a setting that doesn't work!!!**